# How to convert std::future<T> to std::future<void>?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

I have a situation where I have a `std::future<some_type>` resulting from a call to API A, but need to supply API B with a `std::future<void>`:

```
std::future<some_type> api_a();

void api_b(std::future<void>& depend_on_this_event);
```

In the absence of proposed functionality such as `.then()` or `when_all()`, is there any efficient way to throw away the value attached to a `std::future<T>` and be left only with the underlying `std::future<void>` representing the event's completion?

Something like the following could work but would be potentially inefficient:

```
auto f = api_a();
f.wait();
auto void_f = std::async(std::launch::defer, []{});
api_b(void_f);
```

Comment: You figured out by yourself the only solution. This is why C++ needs `future.then` so much. In the meantime, consider boost.threads, that has experimental support for composable futures.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed that `future.then` would be functionally correct. However, I think it might still be more expensive than necessary for the use case above -- I just want to "cast" an existing future to `void`. Ideally this wouldn't require enqueueing a continuation.

Comment: Better than `.then` would be a `promise` type with `on_wait` and `on_timed_wait` APIs.  Forwarding the `wait` and `wait_for` functions to the "wrapped" `std::future` would then be easy, and wouldn't require synchronization at creation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best you can get is probably this:

```
auto f = api_a();
auto void_f = std::async(std::launch::deferred,[fut = std::move(f)]{ fut.wait();});
api_b(void_f);
```

Comment: As a downside, the above will never be `ready()` until you `wait()`.  Even timed waits will never be done.  So you have to audit the consuming code to ensure they are ok with deferred futures, as they behave differently than async futures do in practice.

Comment: This could be avoided by leaving out `std::launch::defer` at the expense of potentially starting another thread and the accompanying performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class U>
struct convert_future_t {
  template<class T>
  std::future<U> operator()( std::future<T>&& f ) const {
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred,
      [f=std::move(f)]()->U{ return f.get(); }
    );
  }
}
template<>
struct convert_future_t<void> {
  template<class T>
  std::future<void> operator()( std::future<T>&& f ) const {
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred,
      [f=std::move(f)]()->void{ f.get(); }
    );
  }
}
template<class U, class T>
std::future<U> convert_future( std::future<T>&& f ) {
  return convert_future_t<U>{}(std::move(f));
}
```

this is a generic version of @sbabbi's answer.

```
api_b( convert_future<void>( api_a() ) );
```

that allows for any target and dest type to work transparently.

The large downside to this approach is that the resulting future is a deferred future wrapping a (possibly async) future, which means that `.wait_for()` and `.ready()` APIs do not work like async futures do.  The returned future will never be ready until waited.

So we can improve this marginally:

```
template<class T>
struct ready_future_t {
  template<class...Us>
  std::future<T> operator()( Us&&...us ) const {
    std::promise<T> p;
    p.set_value(T(std::forward<Us>(us)...));
    return p.get_future();
  }
};
template<>
struct ready_future_t<void> {
  using T=void;
  // throws away the Us&&...s
  template<class...Us>
  std::future<T> operator()( Us&&...us ) const {
    std::promise<T> p;
    p.set_value();
    return p.get_future();
  }
};
template<class T, class...Us>
std::future<T> ready_future(Us&&...us){
  return ready_future_t<T>{}(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
}
template<class U>
struct convert_future_t {
  template<class T>
  std::future<U> operator()( std::future<T>&& f ) const {
    if (f.wait_for(0ms)==std::future_status::ready)
      return ready_future<U>(f.get());
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred,
      [f=std::move(f)]()->U{ return f.get(); }
    );
  }
};
template<>
struct convert_future_t<void> {
  template<class T>
  std::future<void> operator()( std::future<T>&& f ) const {
    if (f.wait_for(0ms)==std::future_status::ready)
      return ready_future<void>();
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred,
      [f=std::move(f)]()->void{ f.get(); }
    );
  }
};
```

where at least if the future was already ready by the time we converted it, the returned future is also ready.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ad345082926788f)

Comment: `return f.wait()` looks wrong  since `std::future<T>::wait()` returns void. Have you tested your code?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky no, but did you reload before commenting?  I specialized the `void` cases I think.  Ah, I missed one in `ready_future`, which doesn't involve a `wait()`, fixed.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Isn't that special-cased in [stmt.return]/3?

Comment: @Yakk `future<void>` does have a `void get()` AFAIK. Why not use it? (Btw IMHO it's rather annoying that `future` requires `ready_future_t` to be specialized for `void`. Is there nothing we can do about it?)

Comment: @dyp we need an invoke helper or something that handles zero-ary args.  Sadly it is needed at both ends: `ready_future<void>( blah() )` will fail if `blah()` returns `void` (but not if any other type).  Not sure what it would have to look like to have 'more generic' function composition.  Or what language features.

Comment: Now that you have removed the specialization, what's the purpose of the class?

Comment: @dyp it is useful in the next version, which requires the specialization.  That is about it.  I did the edit on phone, so did less than I could.