# Adapting a function that returns std::future<T> to std::future<U>

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

Suppose I have an asynchronous functional map primitive which takes a `std::vector` as input and returns a `std::future` to a `Container` of my choice as output:

```
template<class Container, class T, class Function>
std::future<Container> async_map(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
{
  return std::async([=]
  {
    Container result(in.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
      result[i] = f(in[i]);
    }

    return result;
  });
}
```

I'd like to build an analogous `async_for_each` function by adapting `async_map`:

```
template<class T, class Function>
std::future<void> async_for_each(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f);
```

The problem is that `async_for_each` returns `std::future<void>`, while `async_map` returns `std::future<Container>`, and `void` is not a `Container`.

I can get something close to what I want by constructing a type which fulfills the `Container` requirements but ignores assignments to it (`empty_container` in my initial attempt), but a `std::future` of this type is still not `std::future<void>`.

I have the following constraints on my solution:

- There must be only one implementation of `async_map`, with the given function signature (i.e., no `async_map<void>` specialization)
- There must be only one `std::future` created (i.e., no `.then()`-style continuation)

I was hoping there is an efficient way to convert between `std::future`s of related types (or cast a `std::future<T>` to `std::future<void>`), but the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616135/how-to-convert-stdfuturet-to-stdfuturevoid) suggests it is not possible.

Random ideas:

- Can `async_for_each` wrap its function in a clever way to solve this problem?
- Can the type used for `Container` act like `void` in `async_for_each`, but act like `Container` in `async_map`?

My initial attempt is below. Is it possible to build what I want given these constraints?

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class Container, class T, class Function>
std::future<Container> async_map(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
{
  return std::async([=]
  {
    Container result(in.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
      result[i] = f(in[i]);
    }

    return result;
  });
}

struct empty_container
{
  empty_container(size_t) {}

  struct empty
  {
    template<class T>
    empty operator=(const T&) const { return empty(); }
  };

  empty operator[](size_t) { return empty(); }
};

template<class Function>
struct invoke_and_ignore_result
{
  Function f;

  template<class T>
  empty_container::empty operator()(T&& x) const
  {
    f(std::forward<T>(x));
    return empty_container::empty();
  }
};

template<class T, class Function>
//std::future<void> async_for_each(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
std::future<empty_container> async_for_each(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
{
  invoke_and_ignore_result<Function> g{f};

  std::future<empty_container> f1 = async_map<empty_container>(in, g);

  return f1;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec(5, 13);

  async_for_each(vec, [](int x)
  {
    std::cout << x << " ";
  }).wait();

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are using the wrong primitive.

Here I build everything up with a different primitive -- a sink.

A sink can consume data via `operator()(T&&)&`.  It then returns some result via `operator()()&&`.

Here is a `async_sink` function:

```
template<class Container, class Sink>
std::future<std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Sink>()>>
async_sink(Container&& c, Sink&& sink)
{
  return std::async(
    [c=std::forward<Container>(c), sink=std::forward<Sink>(sink)]
  {
    for( auto&& x : std::move(c) ) {
      sink( x );
    }

    return std::move(sink)();
  });
}
```

Here is an implementation of a `sink` that puts things into a container, then returns it:

```
template<class C>
struct container_sink_t {
  C c;
  template<class T>
  void operator()( T&& t ){
    c.emplace_back( std::forward<T>(t) );
  }
  C operator()()&&{
    return std::move(c);
  }
};
```

Here is a sink that takes a function and a sink and composes them:

```
template<class F, class S>
struct compose_sink_t {
  F f;
  S s;
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T&& t){
    s(
      f(std::forward<T>(t))
    );
  }
  std::result_of_t<S()> operator()()&&{
    return std::move(s)();
  }
};

template<class C, class F>
compose_sink_t<std::decay_t<F>, container_sink_t<C>>
transform_then_container_sink( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

Here is a sink that takes a function, calls it, and returns `void`:

```
template<class F>
struct void_sink_t {
  F f;
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T&& t)
  {
    f(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
  void operator()() {}
};
template<class F>
void_sink_t<std::decay_t<F>> void_sink(F&&f){return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

now your map is:

```
template<class Container, class T, class Function>
std::future<Container> async_map(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
{
  return async_sink(
    in,
    transform_then_container_sink<Container>(std::forward<F>(f))
  );
}
```

and your for_each is:

```
template<class T, class Function>
std::future<void> async_for_each(const std::vector<T>& in, Function f)
{
  return async_sink(
    in,
    void_sink(std::forward<F>(f))
  );
}
```

I freely use C++14 features, because they made the code better.  You can replace the move-into-container with a copy for a touch less efficiency, and write your own `_t` aliases.

The above code has not been tested or run, so there are probably bugs in it.  There is one issue I'm uncertain of -- can a lambda returning void end with a `return void_func()` in that context? -- but as that uglyness is in one spot, it can be worked around even if it doesn't work.

Comment: "Can a lambda returning void end with..." Yes. See the first example in my answer.