# Is it possible to transform a future type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

Using a library that has a method like this one:

```cpp
std::future<bool> action();
```

I find my self in a situation where I have to conform with project specific `enum` return types like:

```cpp
enum Result { Ok, Failed, ConnectionDown, ServerError };
```

and the call site of action looks like this:

```cpp
std::future<Result> act()
{
  try {
    return _actor->action(); // This returns a different type :(
    // What to do here ??? ^
  } 
  catch (ConnectionError const& e)
  {
    return std::make_ready_future<Result>(Result::ConnectionError);
  }
  catch (ServerError const& e)
  {
    return std::make_ready_future<Result>(Result::ServerError);
  }
}
```

so essentially the library doesn't have specific return codes for error cases, they are rather emitted as exceptions. Handling that is easy because I can construct ready futures with the appropriate value. The problem (ironically) is with the non exceptional path, where the library's `std::future<bool>` has to be transformed to `std::future<Result>`.

It's pointless to `.get()` the result and construct a ready future based on its value (true -> Ok, false -> Failed) because this way I'm removing asynchronicity from my function. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: May the exceptions be raised after the function has returned ? I mean if the value is not yet available when the `future` is returned. If this is the case, the catch blocks would miss it.

Comment: Related to [how-to-convert-stdfuturet-to-stdfuturevoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616135/how-to-convert-stdfuturet-to-stdfuturevoid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting for continuation function ([`std::experimental::future::then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then))
, you probably want something like:

```
std::future<Result> act()
{
    return std::async([&](){
        try {
            if (_actor->action().get()) {
                return Result::Ok;
            } else {
                return Result::Failed;
            }
        } 
        catch (ConnectionError const& e) {
            return Result::ConnectionError;
        }
        catch (ServerError const& e) {
            return Result::ServerError;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems that's about it. Deducing this from the question you linked, should I assume that this will only trigger the underlying action when we `.wait` or `.get` the future right?

Comment: Depends of way to call `async` in fact (With `std::launch::deferred`, yes).